# Bash - Write a function that opens the closest directory with a certain name

Tags: function, bash, cd

I want to create a Bash function `goto` that takes 1 argument 

**If** the current directory contains a directory by the name of the argument, `cd` to it

**If** any of the directories of the current directory contains it, `cd` there

etc...

if all paths stemming from the current directory are exhausted, `echo "File could not be found"`

My knowledge of Bash is *extremely rudimentary*; I only know the basic syntax of commands, if-statements and functions.

As such, I would like an explanation of the components (or a link to an explanation elsewhere).

Comment: What if more than one subdirectory contains the target?

Comment: Then choose the one in the subdirectory listed first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play around:

```
goto() { local CDPATH; printf -v CDPATH "%s:" */; cd "$1" 2>/dev/null || echo "File could not be found"; }
```